# Get error while Create ExoPlayer Track selector Dialog

Tags: java, android-studio, exoplayer2.x

```
   public TrackSelectionViewFragment() {
      // Retain instance across activity re-creation to prevent losing access to init data.
      setRetainInstance(true);
    }

    public void init(
            MappedTrackInfo mappedTrackInfo,
            int rendererIndex,
            boolean initialIsDisabled,
            @Nullable SelectionOverride initialOverride,
            boolean allowAdaptiveSelections,
            boolean allowMultipleOverrides) {
      this.mappedTrackInfo = mappedTrackInfo;
      this.rendererIndex = rendererIndex;
      this.isDisabled = initialIsDisabled;
      this.overrides =
              initialOverride == null
                      ? Collections.emptyList()
                      : Collections.singletonList(initialOverride);
      this.allowAdaptiveSelections = allowAdaptiveSelections;
      this.allowMultipleOverrides = allowMultipleOverrides;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(
            LayoutInflater inflater,
            @Nullable ViewGroup container,
            @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      View rootView =
              inflater.inflate(
                      R.layout.exo_track_selection_dialog, container, /* attachToRoot= */ false);
      TrackSelectionView trackSelectionView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.exo_track_selection_view);
      trackSelectionView.setShowDisableOption(true);
      trackSelectionView.setAllowMultipleOverrides(allowMultipleOverrides);
      trackSelectionView.setAllowAdaptiveSelections(allowAdaptiveSelections);
      trackSelectionView.init(
              mappedTrackInfo, rendererIndex, isDisabled, overrides,this);
      return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTrackSelectionChanged(boolean isDisabled, List<SelectionOverride> overrides) {
      this.isDisabled = isDisabled;
      this.overrides = overrides;
    }
  }
```

this my code for make track selector dialog
but i got error on trackSelectionView.init(
mappedTrackInfo, rendererIndex, isDisabled, overrides,this);

need  trackFormatComparator  for fill arguments now only 5 arguments there

Comment: so add it? this is your code, you know what data and objects are present.

Comment: This is code bro,, but am unable to fix ... Am beginner

Comment: if you are a beginner, you shouldn't be fiddling with code you don't understand. study the basics, learn it from the beginning, and create your own

Comment: Well.ok bro i done that..

Comment: so you did that? you wrote this code?

Comment: Ahnn bro. Yess i did

Comment: then you know this code and know exactly what to change where.